# Trying to help but ending up causing more harm than good

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, expressions

I'm writing a paper on Romeo and Juliet and how Frair Lawrence and the Nurse are to blame for Romeo and Juliet's deaths and I'm looking for a word. I've looked at other posts but I just see the same few answers. I'm more looking for one word rather than a statement. I saw things like 'hindering rather than helping' and the slang term 'Verschlimmbesserung' but I feel like they just aren't cutting it.

Comment: Maybe `inadvertent`

Answer (score 0):

A potential option -

**bungle**

> a task carried out in a clumsy or incompetent way.

It doesn’t *quite* have the exact meaning you’re requesting insofar as there’s no requirement for the bungler to have good intentions; one could, for instance, bungle something evil.

Nevertheless, it’s the best I can come up with.